# android expandablelistView setAdapter is ambiguous

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm having and issue with my ExpandableListView setAdapter() method in my class OrderMenu. It's telling me it is ambiguous (The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) is ambiguous for the type ExpandableListView).

```
package com.ucapp.uppercrustapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class OrderMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

//expandable list view variable 
ExpandableListView exv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Remove action bar from screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_menu);
    //find resource expandable list view by ID
    exv = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.itemsList);
    //add an adapter that provides data to the list
    exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

  }//end Order menu class
```

the Adapter class:

```
package com.ucapp.uppercrustapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements ListAdapter {

//context variable
private Context context;
//String Arrays
String [] parentList = {"Breakfats","Lunch"};
String [][] childList = {
        {"Pancake"},
        {"Sandwich"}
};

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return parentList.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childList[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

 }
```

And my XML for OrderMenu:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.OrderMenu" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uc_logo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="242dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/uc_logo"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/uc_logo_3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBTN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/uc_logo"
    android:text="@string/backBTN" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/checkoutBTN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/backBTN"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/backBTN"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/checkoutBTN" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/itemsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: Like ucdevs suggests, I recommend removing the "implements ListAdapter" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`exv.setAdapter((ExpandableListAdapter)new MyAdapter(this));`

or

`public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {...}`

w/o implements ListAdapter

Comment: exv.setAdapter((ExpandableListAdapter)new MyAdapter(this)); this worked thank you. One question... why did the other way not work?

Comment: second method also works, you must to remove unused methods: getView, getCount, etc. they shouldn't be there.